# IE8 - Inside a scaled div, blinking caret is displaying offset from text input

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, textinput

I'm using MS Matrix to scale a div in that contains a text input. Everything scales correctly visually, but the blinking caret is displaying offset. The entered text still appears in the correct position.

The offset seems to be proportional to the amount of scaling applied to the wrapper div.

css

```
#wrapper {
        width: 800px;
        height: 600px;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.86, M12=0, M21=0, M22=0.86, Dx=71.68, Dy=53.7599999999);    
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.86, M12=0, M21=0, M22=0.86, Dx=71.68, Dy=53.7599999999)";
    }
```

html

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input type="text" >
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo or any code? There's not much here to work with.

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it